# Linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I would like to find the solutions of this linear equation :

$$ X + (X^\top C)C = D \tag{$\star$}$$

where $C = (c_{1},\ldots,c_{n})^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $D = (d_{1},\ldots,d_{n})^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are given and non-zero.

I noticed that the equation $(\star)$ is equivalent to :

$$ \tilde{C}X = D \tag{$\star\star$}$$

where $\tilde{C} \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that : $\displaystyle \tilde{C}_{i,j} = \begin{cases} c_{j}c_{i} & \text{if } i \neq j \\ 1+c_{i}^{2} & \text{if } i=j \end{cases}$. To do so, I just said that the $i$-th component of the LHS of $(\star)$ is $\displaystyle (1+c_{i}^{2})x_{i} + \sum_{j \neq i}x_{j}c_{j}c_{i}$.

> My question is this one : is there another method to prove that $(\star)$ is equivalent to $(\star\star)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

As $X$ and $C$ are real $n$-vectors,
\begin{align*}
X+(X^\top C)C
&=X+C(X^\top C)\tag{1}\\
&=X+C(X^\top C)^\top\tag{2}\\
&=X+C(C^\top X)\\
&=(I+CC^\top)X.
\end{align*}

Explanations:

$(1)$: if $u$ is a vector and $s$ is a scalar, we have $[s]u=u[s]$, where on the LHS we identify the $1\times1$ matrix $[s]$ with the scalar $s$, so that $[s]u$ is the scalar multiplication $su$.

$(2)$: the transpose of a real $1\times1$ matrix is the matrix itself.

Comment: Since $C$ is an $n\times 1$ vector and $\left(X^T C\right)$ is $1\times 1$, it helps to always write $C\left(X^T C\right)$ instead of $\left(X^T C\right)C$, so that the rules of matrix multiplication are met.

Comment: @fonini $(X^\top C)C$ is scalar multiplication of vector/matrix, *not* matrix multiplication. This had actually beem explained in remark (1) in my answer. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I know, it's not wrong. But I think it always helps to interpret scalar$\times$vector multiplication as a matrix multiplication. For example, if you remember the eigenvalue equation as $Av=v\lambda$ instead of $Av=\lambda v$, you will have no trouble remembering the formula for the eigenvalue decomposition: $AV=V\Lambda\therefore A=V\Lambda V^{-1}$. But I was just expressing an opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^Tc$ is a scalar, you can move it to anywhere. Say
$$(x^Tc)c=(c^Tx)c=c(c^Tx)=(c\otimes c^T)x$$
So 
$$x+(x^Tc)c=(I+c\otimes c^T)x=\tilde Cx=d$$
where
$$\tilde C=I+c\otimes c^T$$

Comment: Thanks ! I was not familiar enough with $\otimes$ to put things this way.

Comment: Do you know Kronecker tensor product?

Comment: No I didn't ! But I'll look into that ! Thanks